# pdo Prepared statements and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I can't execute my sql in pdo,but it's work without pdo.

```
    try{
        $Attr = 'abc';
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("ALTER TABLE num ADD COLUMN ? VARCHAR(30)");
        $stmt->bindValue(1,$Attr);
        $stmt->execute();
        print_r("<pre>");
        print_r( $stmt->errorInfo());
    }
    catch(exception $e){
        print($e->getMessage);
    }
```

the error info is :

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''abc' VARCHAR(30)' at line 1

But it's right when i execute my sql statement in my mysql.

```
ALTER TABLE num ADD COLUMN abc VARCHAR(30); -- right
```

then i execute this sql:

```
ALTER TABLE num ADD COLUMN 'abc' VARCHAR(30); -- wrong
```

the error info is :

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''abc' VARCHAR(30)' at line 1

the same as the first info.

so,why and how to solve ?

Comment: You can't bind columns/tables.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php
`$stmt = $dbh->prepare("ALTER TABLE num ADD COLUMN :name VARCHAR(30)"); $stmt->bindParam(':name', $Attr);`

Comment: @MirekKowieski nope, can't bind tables/columns.

Comment: @chris85 Yes, that's true. He can bind tables like that
`$stmt = $dbh->prepare("ALTER TABLE num ADD COLUMN $Attr VARCHAR(30)");`

Comment: @MirekKowieski that ^ is not considered as "binding", but "assigning".

Comment: @MirekKowieski nowhere a *binding* in your example can be seen